# Project in netbeans getting deployed successfully but not running as expected

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

I am a bit new to java servlets and using netbeans, the problem is, i am not getting the expected output..
This is the `ColorServlet.java` file i have-->

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
public class ColorServlet extends GenericServlet
{

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String s=request.getParameter("s1");
        out.println("<Body bgcolor="+s+"></body>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

And this is the `myhtml.html` file i have-->

```
<html>
    <head><title>This is a Color project</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action="ColorServlet">
            Select your favorite Color
            <select name="s1">
                <option value="Red">Red</option>
                <option>Green</option>
                <option>Yellow</option>
            </select>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value ="OK"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And when i run this project, like this --> `http://localhost:8080/ColorProject/ColorServlet`
I can only see a total black screen on my browser.. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Please use HttpServlet.

Answer (score 0):

You need HttpServlet to get request and construct response. Change your servlet like this

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

@WebServlet(name = "ColorServlet", urlPatterns = {"/ColorServlet"})
public class ColorServlet extends HttpServlet
{

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest request,ServletResponse response) throws IOException,ServletException
    {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        String s=request.getParameter("s1");
        out.println("<Body bgcolor="+s+"></body>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```